# Google's doodle on kids coding: shortest program solving all the levels

Tags: game, atomic-code-golf

Today's Google doodle is about [Celebrating 50 years of Kids Coding](https://www.google.com/doodles/celebrating-50-years-of-kids-coding):
The goal is program the path of a little bunny so that it can eat all the carrots. There are 4 types of blocks (see pictures below):

[image: block description]

From left to right:

- `O("...", k)` = orange piece: these are `for` loops which executes k times the program `"..."`.
- `G` = green piece: go one step forward if you can, otherwise do nothing
- `Bl` = blue piece: turn right and stay on the same block
- `Br` = blue piece: turn left and stay on the same block

[image: big program]

The code above can be written as

```
O(O(G G Br, 4) Bl Bl, 23)
```

Each block (`G, Bl, Br, O(...,k)`) counts as 1 unit, so this program is of length 7. Note than the value of `k` is included inside the 1 unit of `O`.

There are 6 levels. To finish a level you need to eat all the carrots. It is not a problem if your program is not fully executed, the level finishes directly when you eat the last carrot.

We assume that all the 4 types of blocks are available in every level.

> **Your task is to find a single program which solves every level of the game.
>
>    Shortest program in blocks wins.**

Screen shots of each level:
Level 1: [image: level 1 screenshot]
Level 2: [image: level 2 screenshot]
Level 3: [image: level 3 screenshot]
Level 4: [image: level 4 screenshot]
Level 5: [image: level 5 screenshot]
Level 6: [image: level 6 screenshot]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Not my answer

6 blocks

The user [Alex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86858/alex) found a shorter solution, of length 6. I can confirm that their solution works:

```
O(O(Br G G, 6) Br, 5)
```

[image: 6 blocks]

<sup>They attempted to edit this question to add this answer, so I'm assuming they want it to be displayed here. I don't like how the reputation system works around here.</sup>

<sup>The message they left:</sup>

> The editor doesn't have 10 rep, but does have a solution of length 6. O(O(RGG,6)R,5)

<sup>After a few days they responded again via editing the post with: *"Thanks for doing this. Editing this was the only way I saw to get a message. I am happy it exists at all. Feel free to bring it into a new post if you want though."*</sup>

## Old answer

7 Blocks

```
O(O(G G Br, 4) G Br, 100)
```

Patience required.

Edit: The image was wrong.
[image: 7 blocks]

Comment: Good find! I did try this approach but didn't happen on this particular combination before giving up and going for my 9 block solution.

Comment: The user [Alex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86858/alex) claims to have found a shorter solution.

Comment: @JonathanFrech indeed he has! That 10-rep limit is annoying. I get that we have to prevent spam, but shouldn't new users have at least a moderated way of posting answers? Freedom of speech and stuff.

Comment: @R.M I was also a bit irritated upon seeing the problem. I guess SE simply is not designed for one-off answers, as frustrating this probably is for Alex ...

Comment: Why did you edit this into your own old answer instead of posting it as a new answer?

Comment: I believe this is optimal as I made a [quick brute forcer](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yheJF07t2zKGahZwBSC5VVJ4LWSC78tZ/view?usp=sharing) today and it spat out [72 variations of that answer](https://tio.run/##pVQxDoMwENv7ioxFYmg7oLCyMPYN7dThJvp/pVEojc@XSIEuDHZ8ZxzD8/F@hXA/T4tLj9nNvRu63o1jdyL4eiFcVtz/YBzhpsXCcQTgaUrEE0RLNxiW5jE@ThF7XNBLdIcCDYt5UYT1Tsk7F3V8s@gLpwd0qCajcwHn5GWDlZeclUoXsiriXpvJWdnTYqyDEQ59Tb53t67UmR9lenNQJpnzLRRv4kbipirXLEvMlysVGil@tf0y7YQuuErpiWJyrFDieGYzJcWrZgrzOCbjDuhLq1GJwITJfplif/yl64LInzJtxP4okOIc98u4iypH6mKVOyijFrdQ9i/WSA31gXxr@2UhfAA) (although I only verified a few).

Answer (score 13):

Actually, I found a solution with 8 blocks

```
O(O(O(G,4)R,4)GGR,4)
```

Answer (score 7):

### Manually found, 9 blocks

`O(O(GRGLGR,4)L,4)`

I started with the obvious `O(O(GGR,4)L,4)` that solves levels 1-5 then tried a few variations adding effectively-null moves on those levels to find one that would complete level 6. The shortest was a simple right-forward-left in the middle of each "bridge" so the forward move had no effect.

Comment: This is probably optimal which means the challenge is already over. :(

Comment: @totallyhuman turns out the community's not quite done with this yet :P

Comment: "The obvious `O(O(GGR,4)L,4)`" disproves that the shortest solution for level 4 is 7, as shown in the game.

Comment: @mik The game solutions don't rely on changing the loop size or moves that do nothing.

Comment: @totallyhuman you're forecasting was quite wrong :). Even more than a year after the question was posted, a better solution was found.